# Collation for Pivot UnPivot Sql queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, collation

I have a huge problem on my application my sql settings is 'Latin1_General_100_CI_AS' but our customer collation is 'Georgian_Modern_Sort_CI_AS' so when we executing some queries it returns to much problem but we sole that problem with when we use in queries for nvarchar values 'collate Latin1_General_100_CI_AS' keyword so problem solved

BUT

We have some Pivot & UNPIVOT queries and that queries still return problem.

Do you know any solutions for it?

Example

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[Mg_Web_PurchasePerMonths]
(
@Gsm nvarchar(15),
@Year int
)
AS

BEGIN

declare @tbPivot4 table(MshStok varchar(22),

[Jan] money, [Feb] money, [Mar] money, [Apr] money,  [May] money,
[Jun] money, [Jul] money, [Aug] money, [Sep] money,[Oct] money, [Nov] money, 
[Dec] money
)

insert into @tbPivot4
Select MshStok collate Latin1_General_100_CI_AS,isnull([Jan],0) as 
[Jan],isnull([Feb],0) as [Feb],isnull([Mar],0) as [Mar],isnull([Apr],0) as 
[Apr],isnull([May],0) as [May],
isnull([Jun],0) as [Jun],isnull([Jul],0) as [Jul],isnull([Aug],0) as 
[Aug],isnull([Sep],0) as [Sep],isnull([Oct],0) as [Oct],isnull([Nov],0) as 
[Nov],isnull([Dec],0) as [Dec]
From
(
select (select substring(StokNam,0,21) collate Latin1_General_100_CI_AS from 
Stoklar where StokKod = MshStok) collate Latin1_General_100_CI_AS as 
MshStok,(SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(3), DATENAME(MONTH, MshTarih))collate 
Latin1_General_100_CI_AS) as ay,sum(MshTutar) as toplam from Mg_MusHars
inner join Mg_MusCards on MshLoylId = McrIdent
where (McrGsm = @Gsm or @Gsm is null) AND (YEAR(MshTarih) = @Year or @Year 
is null)
group by MshStok,MshTarih
) as gTablo
PIVOT
(
Sum(toplam)
For ay IN ([Jan],[Feb],[Mar],[Apr],[May],[Jun],[Jul],[Aug],[Sep],[Oct],
[Nov],[Dec])
)
as p
   SELECT *
   FROM @tbPivot4
   UNPIVOT
   (
     TotalPurchase FOR Months IN ([Jan],[Feb],[Mar],[Apr],[May],[Jun],[Jul],
     [Aug],[Sep],[Oct],[Nov],[Dec])
   ) AS UNPVTTable

   END
```

Comment: Try to set collation for column in table definition

Comment: Yes that one is choice but our db is very huge and so many app working on that that move a bit risky do you have other sugession? @ventik

Comment: Change sql server settings so that they will be equal to customer's ones. Maybe it's worth to create separate instance of sql server with the same settings.

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear, WHAT has 2 different collations? Your db and your customer db? But your query selects from 1 only database

Comment: My database settings 'Latin1_General_100_CI_AS', My customer db 'Georgian_Modern_Sort_CI_AS' so when you do some select it returns Collation errors @sepupic and i cant execute this query

Comment: Your procedure selects from only **one** database. I cannot understand where is collation conflict

Comment: @sepupic it is example. I suppose that other procedures and queries may containt temporary tables.

Comment: Guys this example is real this procedure returns result in my db and also can return in my customers db too but when i add this procedure in my application on customer service it doesnt returns any data i suspicious about collation

Comment: I cannot see WHERE this example can have problems and the question was about THIS example and this PIVOT. If you have stored procedures that create temporary tables you should use COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT for every character column in it

Comment: how can i use it? @sepupic

Comment: I cannot understand your problem. The code you posted DOES NOT use temporary tables, table variables only. The collation of varchar fields of table variables IS THE SAME as database collation, so **THIS code has no collation problem**

Comment: In case you use temporary tables (#tmp, not @tmp) you should define every varchar column using COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT, doing so your code will execute well on both your server and customer server, because it will define the right collation depending on the collation of database where it's executing

Comment: Example: create table #tmp (col1 varchar(100) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT, col2 varchar(200) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT, ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I declare table i forgot to put collation there when i put my problem solved.

```
declare @tbPivot4 table(MshStok collate Latin1_General_100_CI_AS varchar(22),

[Jan] money, [Feb] money, [Mar] money, [Apr] money,  [May] money,
[Jun] money, [Jul] money, [Aug] money, [Sep] money,[Oct] money, [Nov] money, 
[Dec] money
)
```

Thanks for help!